# iOS and internationalization - all files in one AppStore package?

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, app-store

I've a question about internationalization, but I've failed googling it, so I decided to ask it here.

I'm writing an app that contains a lot of heavy resources (images and movie clips). Also, I need to create the app in several language versions. My priority is to keep the package's size as low as possible, since I don't want the user to be forced to download a bundle which contains all possible language versions of the resources. One solution is to create N projects, each one would contain resources in the specific language. It has one main drawback - it would be much harder to maintain.

My question is: if I use Apple's way of localizing the apps (i.e. I'll have several .lproj folders), will the AppStore in the specific country download only required resources in the specific language? If no, how to achieve it without making N projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Store will not dump the rest of the resource files based on the users App Store location. The language and locale is determined on the device; a user can easily switch their language on the device, and use an app that supports that different language without redownloading.

As for a way to do it without creating N projects, there are various ways:

- You could have your images and video clips hosted online, and the device determines which one to access based on the device language. With this, you could either download on demand (but the app would require constant network access), or download all the required files on first run of the application (and re-download if the language on the device changes, which isn't that often)
- This is more for the images, but you can have two components to the image. A background, which contains no language specific content, and an overlay, that does contain language specific content. The backgrounds would stay constant for all languages, and the appropriate overlay could be applied based on language. If the overlay was only text, then the size of all these overlays would be a lot less than if the whole image was used instead.

Otherwise, you'll need to use N projects. I don't like that idea though, because it would be a pain to maintain in future, but sometimes if your application is media heavy it may be required.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The first solution would be in my case like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but probably is the best way for some serious, bigger projects. The second one unfortunately won't work for the movie clips which contain lots of animated text, different timings and thus can't be replaced by some simple, static overlay. Thanks again for confirming my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: Everyone gets everything.**

All users will - regardless of App Store country - download the entire app - including all resources in all languages the app has available.

You might be living in Denmark, but be preferring English or German on your device. Therefore it doesn't make sense to just supply Danish localizations for Danes. You might also be an Italian living in Germany.